# Balance means in r

Tags: r

I am working on getting a Balanced mean from a table in r. In the table below I would like to return the mean for each location but if there is more then one total for a "Name" per location I would like to take the mean for that than get the mean.

```
Name  Loc  Total
Jeff  IA     17
Jill  IA     67
Jeff  IL     12
Jeff  IL     13
Jill  IL     45
Jeff  MN     32
Jill  MN     65
Jeff  WI     23
Jill  WI     67


name <- c("Jeff", "Jeff", "Jeff", "Jeff", "Jeff", "Jill", "Jill", "Jill", "Jill")
loc <- c("IL", "IL","MN","WI","IA", "IL", "MN","WI","IA")
total <- c(12, 13, 32, 23, 17,  45, 65, 67, 67)

table <- data.frame(name, loc, total) %>% arrange(location)
```

If I return the mean for this I get

```
t3 <- aggregate(total ~ location, table , mean)

IA 42.00000
IL 23.33333
MN 48.50000
WI 45.00000
```

But there are 3 values for IL Jeff has 2 under his name so the mean for IL should be ((12 + 13)/2 + 45)/2 = 28.75

Can this be done in R. I am stumped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are already using `dplyr`, so a solution would be

```
table %>% group_by(loc, name) %>% 
  summarize(total=mean(total)) %>% 
  summarize(total=mean(total))
#      loc total
#   <fctr> <dbl>
# 1     IA 42.00
# 2     IL 28.75
# 3     MN 48.50
# 4     WI 45.00
```

First we group by both loc and name. After the first summarize, we collapse over name so that's no longer grouped. The second summarize uses the per-name means.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base `R` alternative using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(total ~ loc, data = aggregate(total ~ loc + name, data = table, FUN = mean), FUN = mean)

  loc total
1  IA 42.00
2  IL 28.75
3  MN 48.50
4  WI 45.00
```